# Can't switch Docker to Windows Containers

Tags: docker

When I press the option to switch to Windows containers in Docker, it endlessly tries to start the Docker Engine and any docker command I use returns:

> ERROR: error during connect: this error may indicate that the docker
> daemon is not running: Get
> "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/_ping": open
> //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.

I tried many solutions found online, for example the one shown in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dYiPms0xnIE, but to no avail.

Also I checked many questions here on SO, still to no avail.

I'm using this version of Windows:
[image]

And Linux containers work perfectly. Even if I switch to Windows containers and then back to Linux containers without reloading the application Linux containers will still work.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong so I may have omitted some essential information. I'll gladly answer any question on the matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, your Windows version is not supported for Windows containers:

> Note
>
> *To run Windows containers*, you *need Windows 10 or Windows 11*  ***Professional or Enterprise edition***. *Windows Home or Education editions will only allow you to run Linux containers*.

From: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/windows-install/

Comment: Oh I see! Then why giving me the option of selecting it in the first place? In such a case I would expect the option to be greyed out or at least to have a popup warning me. What were they thinking??? :I

Thanks buddy!

Comment: Welcome!Good question/comment: i assume, because it was little cheaper to display the button and fail ..than to (check and) hide it ..;(

Comment: Damn xD Well you live and learn! Thanks again! You spared me some pain at least